# vtkSmartPointer with Android

Tags: c++, android-ndk, vtk

Just what may be a simple question but, while looking at the code for all the examples on Android, I noticed that `vtkSmartPointer<>` are not used at all in the examples. Is there any particular reason for that? I kind of got used to using them now and I was wondering if their use might lead to some issues or not?

For instance this is the `struct` used in VolumeRenderer:

```
struct userData
{
  vtkRenderWindow *RenderWindow;
  vtkRenderer *Renderer;
  vtkAndroidRenderWindowInteractor *Interactor;
};
```

I just tried to re-implement this example using only smartpointers and I'm not running into any issue so far but I was wondering if that was a good idea or not.
So this is what I have for the exact same structure:

```
struct userData
{
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> RenderWindow;
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> Renderer;
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkAndroidRenderWindowInteractor> Interactor;
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No idea about android NDK, but usually it matters who owns the pointer. Are you sure userData is the ultimate owner here?

Comment: Nope, I'm not sure at all to be honest. Just starting to dive into the code and I'm still kind of a beginner with both VTK and the NDK. But I thought it would be a good question as far as best practice are concerned. Especially with the NDK, dealing with Segfault and memory management issues is a pain in the *** so was just wondering if it could be the source of any issue

Comment: Looks like you need a better understanding of pointer in C++ in general before you can study a paritucar NDK. I recommend you to get familiar with general principles of memory management. Like I said, it matters who owns the pointer.

Comment: I understand and know the theory behind memory management and I know that smart pointers make memory management easier by automatically taking care of allocation and de-allocation of memory.

Comment: I can only repeat myself. You need to really understand it. So far you do not. You think smart pointers are something like silver bullet or fairy powder. Pepper your code with it, and it automatically becomes memory-problems free. Nothing could be farther for truth.

Comment: I understand the concept of ownership. It's just that not knowing exactly how and why NDK and VTK work together I cannot tell you exactly what I need to do with the pointers at all. I do not know if they will be instantiated or changed within the class only or from outside the class. That's what I initially meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no issue at all in using vtkNew and/or vtkSmartPointer in your Android (or iOS) applications. In this case vtkNew looks more appropriate and maintains strong ownership, if you need to set these members externally for some reason then vtkSmartPointer would be the way to go.

For more information on which pointer class is appropriate I would recommend taking a look at this [Source article](http://www.kitware.com/source/home/post/7)

Comment: Without knowing the ownership of pointers (and OP claims no knowledge) your advice is an anti-advice.

Comment: I think that is somewhat beyond the scope of the question, of course you need to figure out ownership. The fact remains that the smart pointer classes in VTK work as intended with the Android NDK, and in general are preferred over raw pointers.

Comment: @SergeyA I think Marcus perfectly answered my question. I wanted to know what was preferred with VTK for android, I am not talking about theoretical differences between them in terms of ownership which I do understand. Thanks Marcus.

Answer (score 2):

It mostly depends on the use-case of userData. Using vtkSmartPointer will increment the ref counter and therefore as long as userData is valid, you will have the other pointers valid too. However, in this case, you are storing references to render window objects which could go away because of some external event in that case you want to consider using vtkWeakPointer.